# Working groups, 2 different approaches

Tags: interaction-design, qualitative-analysis, crm

I am building a working group module for a CRM. The goal of the module is allowing user to share anything under a specific domain.

### With working group module users can create:

- A sales team
- A project team
- An organization (e.g. people who run a specific campaign)
- A contract team (imagine that you must prepare a proposal for your client in a certain time and you create a temporary team for this task)
- A discussion team (e.g. brainstorming)
- Or a department (this is the thing that ruins everything)

### Authorization of group:

- Can be public
- Can be closed
- Can be isolated

### Relations:

Group module must be adaptable for following modules:

- Document management system (Please think about authorized user).
- Other modules (leads, branches, email, contacts, etc.) which require authorized user for using them.

### I would like to choose one of approaches I indicated below.

1. Grouping module just like Facebook

   No pain for integrations of modules and their authorization. In this case each group      has it's own authorization system. But in this case I have to design a different module for departments of business. Thus, the question appears in my mind is why should I separate departments and other teams or organizations. They both seems like similar operations. (Sales(a department), Sales of "ABC product"... I want to allow users to share for "sub-departments" too)
2. Using CRM in a workspace

   Creating departments or teams or organizations initially. Then choosing one of them which logged in user get involved. In this case all other modules (leads, sales, contacts etc.) and a complex authorization system must be integrated well with this workspace logic.

Which one seems good to you? And why?

Comment: "a department (this is the thing that ruins everything)"  Talk about a great typo!

Comment: @latefreak which option did you choose in the end?

Answer (score 0):

"Using CRM in a workspace" - This one, it may seem complex at the beginning, but it helps users who want to monitor all the work groups in their company, or some branches. With that, they will not have to be assigned to each working group individually.